# android + php + mysql + register errors

Tags: php, android, mysql, error-handling, registration

I am creating a simple register form on Android to create new use and store data in a database using PHP MySQL.

The application works well but the problem is that the system inserts data to the database but it displays on the emulator the error message. How do I fix this error??? Can anyone can help me??

## register.java

```
package com.sencide;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidRegister extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText uname, upass;
    Button registerBtn;
    TextView result;

    String user, pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            registerBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
            registerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttxt);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == registerBtn)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    registerData();
                }
            };
            t.start();

        } 
    }

    public void registerData()
    {
         uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
         user = uname.getText().toString();


         upass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
         pass = upass.getText().toString();

         try
         {
             // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                Log.e("Response-->", "after httpclient");
            /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/register.php");
                Log.e("Response-->", "after httppost");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.e("Responce-->", "after using the list name pair");

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.e("Responce-->", "after execute the http response");
                String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
                Log.d("STR", str);

                if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            result.setText("register Successful");
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            result.setText("Duh no register");

                        }
                    });
                }

         }
          catch (ClientProtocolException e)
          {     
              e.printStackTrace(); 
           } 
          catch (IOException e)
          {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }




    }




}
```

## log cat

```
04-07 22:04:02.932: E/Response-->(469): after httpclient
04-07 22:04:02.932: E/Response-->(469): after httppost
04-07 22:04:03.033: E/Responce-->(469): after using the list name pair
04-07 22:04:03.033: W/SENCIDE(469): Execute HTTP Post Request
04-07 22:04:03.552: E/Responce-->(469): after execute the http response
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <br />
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning xe-scream' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for</th></tr>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\register.php on line <i>27</i></th></tr>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0593</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>142592</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\register.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\register.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.3134</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>150008</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array' target='_new'>mysql_fetch_array</a>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\register.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\register.php<b>:</b>27</td></tr>
04-07 22:04:03.626: D/STR(469): </table></font>
```

## register.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="*****"; // Mysql username
$password="****"; // Mysql password
$db_name="testlogin"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$message = "";

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, password)VALUES('$myusername', '$mypassword')")or die(mysql_error());

$message = "you have  now been registered";

$getid = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $getid['username'];

?>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: sir i am new to stackoverflow  and i did explain what is the error and what i expected to have as a result can you help me ??

Comment: @user2254979: I added a likely solution below. Did it help?

Answer (score 4):

The error is in your PHP file. If you look at your logcat, you have:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\register.php

That suggests to me that you are not connected to the database, or your query is malformed, or you don't have access to the tables you are trying to read. The PHP manual shows that [the mysql_query function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) can return false - this is responsible for creating the `$sql` variable.

Try this instead:

```
$getid = @mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

That will show you what the error is - it might be worth debugging this at the PHP end - it's much harder via Android and logcat!

Incidentally, I don't recommend you use the error suppression operator (`@`) in live code unless you know what you are doing. It can make debugging much harder, so take care with it.